# Updating position of an object with constant speed, regardless of direction

Tags: performance, algorithm, line, pong

I think this question is a little but stupid but I can't find the answer.

I'm doing the classic game pong. And I want that the ball goes at the same speed for any angle. But with my current algorithm (incrementing x by one and calculating y) if the a in y=ax+b is high there is big gaps between each pixel. What step should I use?

Comment: You want to use type double/float to store the x, y as well as speed values for the ball then use as int cast only when drawing it. Then follow Dukeling example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have something like this:

```
  newPoint
  |\
  | \
y |  \ r
  |  θ\
  |-----
     x  oldPoint
```

What you basically want is to make a step in distance related to r, not x.

From elementary trig:
`cos θ = x/r`
and `sin θ = y/r`

So `newX = oldX + r * cos θ`
and `newY = oldY + r * sin θ`

You can play around with `r`'s value (this will basically be the speed of movement).

`θ` will be the direction of the ball.

Answer (score 2):

you set a default `speed`. Then you can use `x+=speed*cos(theta)` and `y+=speed*sin(theta)`.

when hit, you should change the `theta`.